# flash media server (FMS) reattach camera to new stream

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, camera, flash-media-server, netstream

I'm using flash media server and trying to record the stream but having a problem as I've outlined below. Thanks for taking the time to read this post.

How do I detach my camera from one stream and attach it to a new stream? What I'm trying to do is record the camera stream for 10 seconds and then play it live on a different stream..I try to `netstream.close` and then `netstream.attachCamera(cam0)` but it won't let me attach it to the second new stream. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to close the stream. You can use the attachCamera method with a null argument.

```
netstream.attachCamera(null);
```

Comment: stream0.attachCamera(cam0);
   stream0.publish("stream00", "live");
   var metaData:Object = new Object(); 

     metaData.roomname = "room0";
  metaData.duration = "live"; 
  metaData.width = cam0.width; 
  metaData.height = cam0.height; 
  stream0.send("@setDataFrame" , "onMetaData", metaData);

Comment: I had to do both netstream.attachCamera(null); and netstream.close other wise the recorded file was corrupt